# Proof of Wiener-Ikehara in Montgomery and Vaughan

Tags: number-theory

On p. 263 of Multiplicative Number Theory I, by Montgomery and Vaughan, the authors fix a constant $T\ge 1$ and define functions $\Delta_T(x)=T\left(\frac{\sin \pi Tx}{\pi Tx}\right)^2$
and $J_T(x)=\frac{3T}{4}\left(\frac{\sin \pi Tx/2}{\pi Tx/2}\right)^4$. On line 4 they state that these functions have total mass $1$, and on page 264, in the paragraph that begins ``By Fubini's theorem...'' they state that the Fourier transforms $\widehat{\Delta_T}(t)$ and $\widehat{J_T}(t)$ vanish for $\vert t\vert\ge T.$

My question is: can a kind reader please supply either a proof or a reference for these results? As far as I can see these functions are not discussed anywhere else in the book. They are given the names Fejer kernel and Jackson kernel respectively, but this notation conflicts with all other sources that I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions) of Fourier transforms. Your function $\Delta_T(x)$ is proportional to $\text{sinc}^2(ax)$, with $a=T$. The FT of the squared [normalized sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is the [triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function), which indeed vanishes outside an interval around the origin. Depending on which Fourier transform definition you are using, it vanishes outside $[-a,a]$, or outside $[-2\pi a,2\pi a]$.

As for the function $J_T(t)$, it's proportional to the square of $\text{sinc}^2(ax)$ with $a=T/2$, so the FT of $J_T$ is the convolution of the FT of the $\text{sinc}^2(ax)$ function with itself; this convolution vanishes outside $[-2a,2a]$ (if you're using the right definition of FT).

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer!